# Visualizing a hierarchy of rectangles with neo4j?

Tags: graph, d3.js, neo4j, visualization

I am thinking of using neo4j to store a graph database. My data basically consists of a hierarchy of rectangular regions with fixed coordinates: the top node has R rectangles in it, each of those has Q rectangles in it, and so on. The regions do not form a rectangular subdivision. Since I have a lot of data, I would like to be able to present an interface where a user can click on a particular rectangle to see its substructures in more detail, and then be able to click on one of those rectangles to show more detail, and so on. My application would be sort of like Google Maps, where more detailed layers get loaded as a user zooms in. I was thinking of generating tiles to serve to OpenLayers or Leaflet for display, but my data has a graph structure that I would like to take advantage of, and I think using neo4j (possibly in combination with a visualization library like d3.js) may be an easier way to build my tool.

I have these questions about neo4j and the ability to visualize its data:

1. Can data in neo4j be organized into different layers corresponding to different levels of detail?
2. Can neo4j display nodes as rectangles with fixed coordinates on a 2D plane? Can these rectangles be selectable / "zoomable"?

I know neo4j has a default web interface for showing nodes but I'd like to know how customizable this is before committing a lot of time to it. The TreeMap example at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery sort of looks like what I want, but I'd like to show more detailed structure in regions that users select.